# Changing variable of an application from another application

Tags: c#, memory

I have a question about changing an variable of an application from another application.

For example: If in **1.exe** I have defined `string a="a"`, how will I be able to change `a="a" to a="b"` by using another application?

Do I have to get the memory address of string and then change it's content to b? Or Is there any another easier way?

Comment: You can't modify the memory of one process by using another process directly. At least, I hope your OS doesn't allow that. You can pipe commands from one process to another and then add the capability to receive and act on those commands. TGH gives a good alternative solution below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set up a shared resource for the two applications and read the values from there. It could, be a database, cache or even a simple text file.

Refresh the variables from the shared resource when appropriate.

Comment: Good solution of course, communication between processes would of course be another solution, although your solution is of course much more scalable :P

Comment: Yes, I understand the method. I have developed few programs already. Right now I want to learn about game hacking and trying to learn the theory behind it. For example, counter strike, fimiliar game to a lot of us I believe. Normally it takes about 5 shot to kill one guy, but right now I want to make it one shot kill. I believe there's an "attack damage" variable, so if I can be able to change that variable by my apication(hack). I can one shot kill. That's just my guessing. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Given the scenario you have mentioned (i.e. you do not control the code for the 1st application).. The general idea of opening the target process with admin privileges, finding the memory location you want to update, and then updating it applies..

However, be warned that it will generally not be that simple. For example,

- It can be extremely hard to predict, how many copies, of the variable are maintained by the applications logic, and where?
- Without disassembling the code (no way a trivial task.. none of this is), scanning for the value and guessing the memory location is the only option which comes to mind. But it has the risk of making wrong guesses, and corrupting the entire process.

---

PS - There are freely available software, which attempt to do exactly what I've described above.. I'd advise that you try to examine how they work (scenarios they support), to get better idea of what you are trying to accomplish.

PPS - Also **be careful** what you download.. Applications like these, if downloaded from un-reliable sites, can be damaging / security risk.

Comment: I appreciate a lot for your answer. Thank you so much sir!

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way is communication with network sockets in localhost via UDP or TCP. It gives you a good event mechanism so you can easily handle your data without checking the new data changes frequently, also will be doesn't matter how amount of application communicating each other in same time. Other solutions like shared memory etc. will be hard to control especially when you running three and more apps.

Comment: Thank you! I'll get more deeper into that